# create view for allocating material to isometrics

Tags: sql-server

i have to table .
table 1 contains bom of isometric for piping lile this :

```
iso  | code | quantity
---- |----  |----
1100 | a    | 2    
1100 | b    | 1 
1100 | c    | 1
1101 | a    | 3
1101 | d    | 1
```

table 2 that contains inventory of material codes(a,b,c ,d) like this :

```
code | inventory
---    ---
a    |  4
b    |  2
c    |  2
d    |  1
```

i want create view like this :

```
iso | code | quantity | allocated | inventory
---   ---    ---        ---          ---
1100| a    |   2      |  2        |  2
1100| b    |   1      |  1        |  1
1100| c    |   1      |  1        |  1
1101| a    |   3      |  2        |  0
1101| d    |   1      |  1        |  0
```

Comment: How does `allocated` being calculated?

Comment: allocated=quantity unless inventory is less than quantity, if inventory < quantity then allocated=inventory